# How to deal with double foreign keys in Django while creating an API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created these models for my database. It's supposed to be kind of a tree (country>multiple cities>multiple airports). The problem is I want to use autocomplete which would show not only the name of an airport and the name of the city, but also the name of the country. I'm stuck because I don't know how to add the country to my API (together with airports of course). Is there a way to do it or maybe I should change the architecture of my database?

```
class Country(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Airport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = city.country #how can I do this?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' (' + self.abbr + ')'
```

from serializers.py:

```
class AirportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Airport
        fields = ['name', 'city']
```

from views - creating custom search API:

```
class AirportList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class =AirportSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        airport = self.kwargs['airport']
        list_airports = Airport.objects.filter(name__icontains = airport)
        return list_airports
```

Path in case it's helpful:

```
re_path('^airports/(?P<airport>.+)/$', views.AirportList.as_view()),
```

script for autocomplete:

```
<script>
    new Autocomplete ('#autocomplete', {
        search: input=>{
            console.log(input)
            const url = `/airports/${input}/`
            return new Promise(resolve =>{
            fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>{
                const mappedPosts = data.map((airport)=>{return (airport.name + ', ' + airport.city) ;})
                console.log(mappedPosts)
                resolve(mappedPosts)
            })}

            )
        }
    })


</script>
```

how it looks now:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new field to the serializer and use [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument to specify how to fetch required data:

```
class AirportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    country = serializers.CharField(source='city.country.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Airport
        fields = ['name', 'city', 'country']
```

Please note that this will make an additional query for each airport in the list. To avoid it you may add [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in your view:

```
class AirportList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class =AirportSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        airport = self.kwargs['airport']
        list_airports = Airport.objects.filter(name__icontains = airport).select_related('city__country')
        return list_airports
```